# Is there another way to access the Name property in one-liner?

Tags: powershell

Environment:
PowerShell 5.1
Windows 2016 Standard
Window 10 Pro

Is there another way to access the Name property in a one-liner?

```
$sspLatestVer = Invoke-Command -Session $hostSession -ScriptBlock { (Get-ChildItem $using:versionFolder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name }
```

Comment: You're already accessing the value of the `Name` property, can you clarify what your expected result is?

Comment: Can you use a pipe instead of enclosing in parens

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1`

Comment: you are already using the most efficient method. piping to `Select-Object` will slow things down [minutely] due to the added pipeline step. ///// also, your code is NOT a one-liner. [*grin*] you need to define the 2 $vars used in the part you show. ///// also also, forcing a "one liner" is almost always an error. it is also one of the indicators of severe `m3 s0 lee7!`-ism. avoid that trap ... and it is a trap.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey What is m3 s0 lee7! ism?

Comment: it is my attempt at "leet speak". `m3` = me, `s0` = so, `lee7` = leet = elite. it's been more than a decade since it tried to write any of that ... so i pro'ly munged it. [*blush*]

Comment: I concur with @Lee_Dailey. Using the grouping operator is the way to go here. The caveat is that, it isn't better for long running commands such as providing the `-Recurse` parameter. This is because, the entirety of the command has to execute first before you can use dot notation to reference the property. In those scenarios, sometimes it is better to pipe to `Select-Object`. Seeing as you're not using the `-Recurse` switch, I'd recommend using: `(Get-ChildItem $using:versionFolder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending)[0].Name`

Comment: you're so h4x0r @Lee_Dailey :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - [*grin*]